# Wrap text with indent in WPF textBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, word-wrap, textblock

I am using a listbox to display undo redo list with data template as:

```
<ListBox x:Name="actionList"
           Height="150"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           MouseMove="ListBoxMouseMove"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
           SelectionMode="Extended"
           Style="{StaticResource CustomListBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Width="235"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   FontSize="11"
                   Text="{Binding DisplayText}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

It is working as expected, but for long undo redo string the wrapping occurs but it is aligned to first chracter of the line. we want it to indent a bit to clearly identify the two list items. Illustrated as follows:

[image: Word wrap desired functionality]

How can we achieve the same.

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is not possible *easily*. You'd have to work out what part of the string is on a new line and indent that part of the string inside a `RichTextBox`. That would cause countless headaches. Perhaps a design change would be what's required here? Maybe you could provide some **padding for the text** so the items in your list are spaced further apart.

Answer (score 2):

They "easier" way to do this would probably involve using a **Paragraph** object to represent the text.

Paragraphs natively support indentation with properties like **TextIndent** (controls first line indentation, and you can set it to a negative value) or **Margin** (sets a margin for the whole paragraph, but respects the first line indentation).

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        // IsHitTestVisible is set to false to avoid FlowDocument's built-in text selection
        //     from disrupting the regular ListBox mouse selection behavior
        <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                 <FlowDocument FontSize="12"
                               FontFamily="Calibri" 
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               PagePadding="0">
                     <Paragraph TextIndent="-10" 
                                Margin="10,0,0,0">
                         <Run Text="{Binding ., Mode=OneWay}" />
                     </Paragraph>
                 </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: How can we put Paragraph as a listbox item??

Comment: Edited my answer with a code example, and removed the BindableRun thing since Run is indeed bindable since 4.0 (the example uses a ListView instead of a ListBox, but you can see the idea :P)

Comment: It did worked but lost the listbox functionality and styling. I was not able to show the selected item & styling the same is too much task.

Comment: I see... It worked with a ListView, but I just checked with a ListBox and it's like you say. I managed to get it working as intended by using `IsHitTestVisible="False"`, so I'll edit my answer in case someone else finds it useful.